# What is \n\nnd supposed to do?

Tags: sed

```
echo n | sed '\n\nnd'
```

This command prints `n` with GNU sed. With BSD sed, it doesn't print anything.

The [POSIX sed spec.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02) says:

> - In a context address, the construction `\cBREc`, where `c` is any character other than <backslash> or <newline>, shall be identical to `/BRE/`. If the character designated by `c` appears following a <backslash>, then it shall be considered to be that literal character, which shall not terminate the BRE. For example, in the context address `\xabc\xdefx`, the second `x` stands for itself, so that the BRE is `abcxdef`.
> - The escape sequence `\n` shall match a <newline> embedded in the pattern space. A literal <newline> shall not be used in the BRE of a context address or in the substitute function.

but doesn't elaborate any further on these contradictory statements.

So my question is, which behavior is correct? Or is it intentionally left unspecified?

Comment: NetBSD sed also prints nothing, fwiw. (Not surprising as all the BSDs generally behave the same way when it comes to core utilities). plan9port sed doesn't recognize the construct at all (But it's also not POSIX).

Comment: I see the second bullet as controlling. Saying your `'\n'` *"* ***shall*** *not be used in the BRE of a context address or in the substitute function."*

Comment: Based on the first bullet point, my understanding is that `sed '\n\nnd' <<< n` whose output for me is `n`, should be the same as `sed '/n/d'`, whose output for me is empty.

Comment: You can redirect an entire file as `sed '\n\nnd\n' < file` and you just get the text back. There is nothing to suppress non-matching lines in the `sed` command. You can add a suppression and then `sed` acts as if the regex is invalid matching nothing, e.g. `sed -n '/\n\nnd\n/p'`

Comment: My reading: A `\n` is not a literal newline (That would be character `0x0A`), so `n` should be able to be used as the delimiter in a context address. It also implies that a `\n` inside such a address is a literal n, not a newline escape. So I'd expect it to print nothing.

Comment: Except I take `'\n'` as a *literal <newline>* as `'\n'` or `'\\n'` is the *character-literal* for the newline. It's a good question that turns on the literal interpretation of both bullets. Now I'm not saying I am 100% sure I am 100% correct in my interpretation -- but that interpretation does explain what I see in testing with it.

Comment: I think the correct behavior is to print nothing, as the second `\n` should match the literal `n`, because the backslash is needed to avoid `n` being interpreted as the closing token corresponding to the first `\n`. Having `n` as the output means that you are not able to match any `n` if you use `\n` and `n` to enclose the BRE.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure enough to be authoritative in an answer. There are obviously differences in how GNU and FreeBSD interpret the POSIX standard there -- because I get `'n'` after running the command on Linux -- and others don't. So given that all implementations should be working from the same POSIX standard, there are obviously many that are smarter than I that have difficulty with the interpretation as well. It's is a great question and the answer probably boils down to "It works the way the person coding it interpreted the standard for each implementation." Somebody was confused...

Comment: Interesting question ! Since these two rules cannot be both satisfied in the case of \nBREn and the spec does neither clarify which one must take precedence nor invoke the undefined behavior curse, I'd say that the choice is (unintentionally) left to the implementation. For me both behaviors are equally compliant with the standard here. Indeed having `n` as output means that there is no way to match a literal `n`, but having nothing as output also means that there is no way to match a newline. Not sure which one I prefer. At least GNU provides digit escape sequences to still match anything.

Comment: Well, where are Charles or Ed when you need them? I'll say this, this part of the POSIX standard is just a well written as the strict-aliasing rule in the C-standard is. (to say reasonable minds may disagree on what they say -- is an understatement `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an update; with [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/commit/?id=f5abeba48e4c93fc8df4c81e7ae2a61f469ed5e1) GNU sed no longer prints `n` for the command in OP.

---

According to [a reply to my email on Austin Group mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg05891.html) (quoted below), the standard is unclear on this, and both behaviors are correct. HP-UX and Solaris adopted the GNU behavior too; so it's not a bug in implementations, but a lack of clarity in the standard.

> Neither is more correct than the other because, as you said yourself, the standard is unclear. A formal interpretation would say "The standard is unclear on this issue, and no conformance distinction can be made between alternative implementations based on this."
>
> Given that implementations differ, we should probably make the behaviour explicitly unspecified.